# Alternative to Cursor and While loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In order to handle iteration in SQL server we use `Cursor` or `While` loops. In our application both approaches seems to be costly. 
Any other performance feasible approach which can handle the iteration in sql server?

Comment: Yes you can use `SET based` solution I will say in 85% of cases. Using Loops is bad habit from different language which force you to think in `ROW based manner`. Show your code and we will try to find set based solution ;)

Comment: In *general*, in SQL, you should favour set-based operations. So the answer to "how best do I iterate?" is usually "don't".

Comment: See also [RBAR: 'Row By Agonizing Row'](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/)

Comment: the situation is to copy one week data into multiple weeks. I used while loop to iterate the number of weeks where the data need to be copied. I know only two standard ways to do the iteration cursor and while loop. I prefer while loop here. Appreciate if any sql server technique is there do the job

Comment: @bmsqldev - and that would normally be handled by joining the source table(s) with a numbers table (without further information, can't offer more concrete solution at this time)

Answer (score 1):

If possible, avoid using SQL Server cursors. They generally use a lot of SQL Server resources and reduce the performance and scalability of your applications. If you need to perform row-by-row operations, try to find another method to perform the task.

Here are some alternatives to using a cursor:

- Use `WHILE LOOPS`
- Use temp tables
- Use derived tables
- Use correlated sub-queries
- Use the `CASE` statement
- Perform multiple queries

More often than not, there are non-cursor techniques that can be used to perform the same

Comment: How is a `while loop` different to a cursor? You still process the data row-by-row.

Comment: In `WHILE` loop no objects must be created in memory to facilitate the looping through a set of records as is necessary with a cursor.

Comment: But cursors will take more resources, since it will scan entire table rows for each iteration isn't it?

Comment: So how does the `while` loop actually loop through the rows of a query? How does it retrieve the rows that are processed in the loop? It sure will use a cursor (albeit an implicit one) in the background. Or does it take the data out of thin air?

Comment: I haven't explored that. but generally while loop is preferred over cursors for performance sake